# isset causing getjson to return undefined

Tags: php, jquery, json, forms, validation

I'm having a problem with my code.  I want to validate my form by creating an array to contain a variable when the form is valid.  But to do this I need to use the isset method to know that the information has been posted.  Here's a simple example

http://richbaird.net/clregister

```
<?PHP

if(isset($_POST['username'])) {

$helloworld = array ("hello"=>"world","name"=>"bob");


print json_encode($helloworld);

};

if(!isset($_POST['username'])) {

echo json_encode(array('error' => true, 'message' => 'No username specified'));



?>
```

Simple enough if username has been posted create array helloworld.

I'm using the following method to get the json

```
<script>

//document ready

$(document).ready(function(){

var php = "helloworld.php";

//submit form
$("#loginform").ajaxForm
(

//on successful submission

function() {

//getjson

$.getJSON("helloworld.php",function(data) {

    alert(data.message)

}) //close get json


.error(function(error) { alert(error.responsetext); })
.complete(function() { alert("complete"); });

} // close success

) // close submit




});
//end document ready
</script>
```

I'm using the jquery forms plugin to submit the form.

and my form looks like this

```
<form id="loginform" name="loginform" method="post" action="helloworld.php">
<label for="username">username</label>
<input type="text" name="username" id="username" />

<br />
<label for="password">password</label>
<input name="password" type="password" />

<br />
<input name="submit"  type="submit" value="Login" id="subtn" />

</form>
```

the network console shows the method POST returns {hello:world name:bob}  but the GET returns the no username specified which is what I get in my alert.  It looks like jquery is trying to get the code before it has a chance to process entirely, how can I prevent this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few hours of thinking and a lot of help from juco I realized, I'm making 2 seperate calls in this function.  First I'm posting the data which works, then on a successful post I'm trying to make a seperate call, a GET request, that request contains the callback which is supposed to alert me of the result, however because it makes a 2nd call and it sends a GET request the variable POST is never set and therefore there is nothing to get back.  I revised my code to only use the post method like so.

```
<script>

//document ready

$(document).ready(function(){





// bind form using ajaxForm 
$('#loginform').ajaxForm({ 
    // dataType identifies the expected content type of the server response 
    dataType:  'json', 

    // success identifies the function to invoke when the server response 
    // has been received 
    success:   processJson 
}





); 


function processJson(data) {

alert(data.hello);

}




});
//end document ready
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the quotes. Should be:

```
if(isset($_POST['username']))
```

You should check your console to see whether `username` is actually getting posted, as if it's not, you're not returning any data. You could instead consider returning an error `if(!isset($_POST['username']))`, perhaps something like:

```
echo json_encode(array('error' => true, 'message' => 'No username specified'));
```

**EDIT**
Also, remember it's `$_POST`, not `$_post`

**Second Edit**

Your code will be far more intuitive and readable written like this:

```
$return = array();
if(isset($_POST['username'])) {
    $return = array("hello"=>"world","name"=>"bob");
} else {
    $return = array('error' => true, 'message' => 'No username specified');
}
echo json_encode($return);
```

Comment: Good catch, I added the quotes but still get the same error.  See the edit

Comment: I've made a few edits now! But the last note is probably the most important ;-)

Comment: Cool, so I made the update and did as you said, I am getting the error no username specified which obviously means that it's not being sent with the post.  My question now is why not.  The network tab of my console clearly says helloworld.php method post.  Do you know of some way of seeing exactly what is sent?  The preview also gives me { hello: "world" name: "bob" }

Comment: Have you also changed `$_post` to `$_POST`? (case sensitive)

Comment: Another edit made with a refactor of your code. You should also try a `var_dump($_POST); exit;` and check the results in your console.